# Getting error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')" whenever using app.js in laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
at ./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js (app.js:28291:56)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:85516:42)
at ./node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs (app.js:81734:25)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:85516:42)
at ./resources/js/bootstrap.js (app.js:1209:16)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:85516:42)
at ./resources/js/app.js (app.js:1172:1)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:85516:42)
at app.js:85681:64
at __webpack_require__.O (app.js:85553:23)
```

I have tried unlinking app.js but many features in my project stopped working.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question might need a bit more context to make it clearer. Can you please provide some additional details so that the community can better understand what you're asking?

Comment: Probably need some more context here, but as a general note app.js is the Javascript entry-point responsible for bootstrapping the client-side logic for your Laravel application. So it can be a bit of a red herring when problems appear to come from app.js itself. Looks like more specifically the problem is related to your "follow-redirects" NPM package. It relies on some NodeJS  standard libraries. Perhaps it's unable to resolve the Stream library due to missing or conflicting NodeJS versions, or misconfiguration. Seeing your app.js and package.json might help.

Comment: Here is the link for app.js @Drowsy

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hajjQxy09ueVg8PxX1VvfA2WXjtXWLrI/view?usp=share_link